# Is there a way to access the history of API requests/calls made to my openAI account?

Tags: python, python-requests, openai-api, gpt-4

I just made ~2k api requests to GPT but my code errored out and did not save (therefore, the calls were made but never stored to code). Is there a way to retrieve the output of those calls?